# How return name of image from FormControl in ReactivForms

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get the name from FormControl of the image in Angular ReactivForms. I got the full path of the image like `file = "C:\fakepath\Screenshot (1).png"` but I want only `Screenshot (1).png`.
I using `control.value` for getting the name of the image.
I want to add I do not have this folder in my C: directory `C:\fakepath\`

This is my method :

```
 requiredFileType(categoryList: CategoryModel[]) {
    return function (control: FormControl) {
      const file = control.value;
      if (file) {
        const extension = file;

        for (let i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++) {

          for (let j = 0; j < categoryList[i].productModel.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct.length; k++) {
              console.log(categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path);
              if (categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path.includes(extension)) {
                console.log(categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path);

                return{
                  requiredFileType: true
                };

              }
            }

          }

        }
        return null;

      }

      return null;

    };
  }
```

Does anyone know the resolution of this?

Answer (score 3):

Use `substring` if your path has static number of characters (not changing):

```
const file = control.value;
const fileName = file.substring(10, str.length);
```

Demo:

```js
let str = "C:\fakepath\Screenshot (1).png";
const mystr = str.substring(10, str.length);
console.log(mystr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` functions in javascript

```
const path = control.value;
const fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\') + 1, path.length);
```

Comment: @Sln san sun, did these answers help at all?